# Why is there a 10 megapixel max for images when syncing to OneDrive? Even over WIFI?

Tags: lumia, sync, video, onedrive, pictures

I can understand if they limit this over mobile to protect me from myself, even though I have an unlimited data plan.  Limiting it over WIFI though make no sense.  My new Nokia Icon has a 20 megapixel camera and I do not want to be forced to lose quality.

Another related question I have is what are the limitations on video? All new phones take 1080p video, but it seems to want to compress the videos when I try to save them to OneDrive.

Why would this limitation be on the Windows Phone but not Android? On my old S3 everything was uploaded without limitation or compression.

I guess what i am asking is, is there a way to upload original quality photos and videos to OneDrive, regardless of quality/size, with a Windows Phone?  Is this something that has been addressed with 8.1?

Comment: How at you uploading the images? I just uploaded a 34 mp image to one drive without a problem

Comment: I'm looking at the auto-syncing feature on the phone.  The Microsoft site says it only syncs pictures under 10 megapixels.  When I tried to upload a 256MB video to OneDrive from the phone, it wanted to compress it before uploading it.  My Android will autosync all pictures and video through the OneDrive app regardless of size.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**
Now this has been confirmed on  [WPCentral article](http://m.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-will-now-backup-your-high-resolution-lumia-photos-onedrive):

> (On WP8.1) enabling the ‘Best Quality’ option under ‘backup to OneDrive’, the high resolution images are rightly saved to your OneDrive Camera roll.

---

According to some comments on [Uservoice.com](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4228225-enable-full-resolution-photo-upload-to-skydrive-on...) it has been addressed in Windows Phone 8.1. Hi resolution photos are reportedly syncyng out of the box now.

[Carlo Mendoza commented, April 16, 2014 20:35](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4228225-enable-full-resolution-photo-upload-to-skydrive-on...):

> It appears this has been addressed in Windows Phone 8.1. My Lumia 1020 now uploads the full 38mp photos to OneDrive

[Richard Durishin commented, April 22, 2014 05:28](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4228225-enable-full-resolution-photo-upload-to-skydrive-on...):

> This is excellent news! Following the upgrade to the 8.1 Preview, I too am getting full 10-12MB photos in my SkyDrive Camera Roll. :)

Well, I do not have any way to check their statements (and that feature request is not marked as *DONE*), but at least I would give it a try.